# How to print final SQL query in Camel-Jdbc which uses Spring JDBCTemplate

Tags: oracle, apache-camel, jdbctemplate, spring-camel, camel-jdbc

Given and Issue:

1. I have Spring boot application.
2. Requirement is we need to print SQL query in Camel-Jdbc which uses Spring JDBCTemplate internally.

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.camel/camel-jdbc -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.6</version>
</dependency>
```

The example query that is generated by our implementation is,
***select empId, empName from employee offset 10 rows?dataSource=dataSource1&template.maxRows=10***

3. As the query - *select empId, empName from employee offset 10 rows*,
   is to be executed on Oracle, MSSQL, MySQL. The camel-jdbc internally converts and send the query to JDBCTemplate, and JDBCTemplate do some internal changes and execute the Query on respective database.

**Issue is we are not getting in the logs what is the final query executed after replacing - offset 10 rows, with the respective database native query.
**
**So, need help in printing out the SQL query.**

I have tried below but didn't get the query in the logs:

```
logging.level.org.springframework.jdbc.core=TRACE
```

and

```
<category name="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
            <priority value="debug" />  
        </category>
```